# Riot v4 view router

Tags: view, router, riot.js

I'm wondering what view router to use with Riot v4 since my usual ones don't currently support v4 and no idea when they will.

I've tried `riot-router` and `riot-view-router` but no joy as they rely on v3.  What is the alternative until a v4 compat module comes about?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any router will do. A proper router is (supposed to be) a small, rather simple, independent piece of code that calls a function per url pattern (just like server side ReST router, for instance) basically.
The called function can mess with the DOM, with the riot components, generate events - whatever fit your needs.

i myself found such a basic router and improved it and i use it happily in my Riot 4 application.

Comment: Good call. I was fixated on a router that set up and changed my views based on the defined routes! I did the same with a few simple js routers but ended up updating riot-view-router to work with Riotv4. For anyone interested check the riotv4 branch: https://github.com/Ataye/riot-view-router/tree/riotv4

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** as of April 2020 you can use `@riotjs/route` (currently v5.3.1). It is documented on the [Riot website](https://riot.js.org/) as being part of the Riot ecosystem and is meant for Riot v4.